# Condiciones en ciclo for

Tags: java

En mi función lo que hago es llenar una matriz con números aleatorios:

```
 public int[][] llenarMatriz(int matriz[][]) {

    for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < matriz[j].length; j++) {

            matriz[i][j] = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
        }
    }

    return matriz;

}
```

La matriz que le paso por parámetro es la siguiente:

```
int matrizP[][] = new int[2][3];
matrizP = matriz.llenarMatriz(matrizP);
```

Pero lo que no entiendo es por qué me manda el siguiente error:

> `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2`

Lo que me retorna `matriz[j].length` siempre sera 3 en este caso, osea ésta es la condición que uso de referencia para no pasarme a otra posición que no exista.

Tener en cuenta que `matriz[j].length` donde `j` se incremente hasta máximo en 1, pero cuando pasa un ciclo y se ejecuta el `matriz[ "aqui j seria 1" ].length` pero manda el error de `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2`.

Para que no mande este error puedo poner `matriz[i].length` osea cambio de iterador y todo se arregla, pero no entiendo por que manda ese error con el iterador `j` si siempre

```
matriz["sea j o i "].length; //sera 3 en este caso.
```

En resumen, el problema esta en el `for` anidado osea el segundo `for`, y su condición de `matriz[j].length`, porque con el iterador `i` funciona pero con el iterador `j` no.

Estuve pensando que: debe ser que un ciclo `for` sólo puede trabajar con una condición que es inmutable hasta que termine su ciclo, osea que un ciclo `for` no es dinámico si lo que se quiere es cambiar el valor de su parámetro de condición. No sé si esto es correcto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La excepcion esta ocurriendo porque el indice sea de las filas o las columnas en algun momento es mas grande que una de las posibles posiciones de tu array

Almacena en una variable la cantidad de filas 0,2,3 = 3 filas 
Almacena en una variable la cantidad de columnas 0,2,3 = 3 columnas

recorre el array con el bucle for y que la condición de cada parte del bucle for sea que mientras i

```
     int filas = 2;
     int columnas = 3;
     int matrizP[][] = new int[filas][columnas];
     matrizP = matriz.llenarMatriz(matrizP,filas,columnas);

     public int[][] llenarMatriz(int matriz[][]) {

        for (int i = 0; i < filas; i++) {

            for (int j = 0; j < columnas; j++) {

                matriz[i][j] = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
            }
        }

        return matriz;

    }
```

Comment: En la segunda iteracion ya no se ejecuta la creacion del iterador, solo se ejecuta  el primer y el ultimo parametro que es el `j++` y luego se ejecuta la condicion `j < matriz[j].length;`
ya en la tercera ejecucion se vuelve a ejecutar el parametro que es el ` j++` y se vuelve a preguntar `j < matriz[j].length;` y en esta validacion esta el error, `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2 ` ya que no existe la posicion `matriz[2][3]`.